# Why does command from Dockerfile fail, while running it manually in the container works perfect?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, debian

I'm creating a simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y

RUN apt install git golang -y
RUN echo "export GOPATH=$HOME" >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN source /root/.bash_profile
RUN echo $GOPATH
```

But it fails at `source /root/.bash_profile` with the error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c source /root/.bash_profile' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I commented that line away, built the image and then ran the same command from within the container, and then it runs fine.

I've tried many variations, including manually calling `/bin/bash`, but it doesn't seem to work from within the `Dockerfile`.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

[EDIT]

I also tried replacing that line by

```
RUN export GOPATH=$HOME
```

and

```
RUN export GOPATH=/root
```

But the echo after it gives an empty result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to your dockerfile :

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y

RUN apt install git golang -y
ARG GOPATH=/PATH/TO/
ENV GOPATH ${GOPATH}
RUN echo $GOPATH
```

that is the correct way to provide the system Variable in Docker , source and export will only works in a single step in the dockerfile

Answer (score -1):

Please check if this works
RUN /bin/bash -c "source /root/.bash_profile"